# f# List.maxBy not typechecking the way I expect

Tags: f#

```
let allEmpty xs = 
    xs |> List.maxBy (fun x -> x |> List.length) = 0
```

that doesn't type check.

this does:

```
let allEmpty xs = 
    xs |> List.maxBy (fun x -> x |> List.length) = []
```

Doesn't maxBy return an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.maxBy` returns the larges element based on the function you give it.

In you case `xs` is a `'a list list` - a list of lists. So you are looking for the longest list in the list of lists.

If you wanted the length of the largest list you would `map` the length first and then use `max`.

```
let allEmpty xs = 
    xs 
    |> List.map (fun x -> x |> List.length) //Get the length of each list in the list
    |> List.max = 0 //See if the largest is empty, if so all are empty.
```

Although this feels a much more natural way to express the intent of the function:

```
let allEmpty xs = 
    xs |> List.forall ((=) [])
```

Or more verbose:

```
let allEmpty xs = 
    xs |> List.forall (fun l -> l |> List.length = 0)
```

Comment: I just realized that.  I thought that maxBy was just shorthand for map and max combined.

Comment: @DaveShaw: actually your second snippet as written detects if a non-empty list is a part of the argument; to implement the original function intent the current boolean result should be negated.

Comment: Because that error is obviously very easy to make, it's better avoid the need for negation altogether: `let allEmpty xs = xs |> List.forall (fun l -> l |> List.length = 0)` -- or even more to the point `let allEmpty xs = xs |> List.forall ((=) [])`

Comment: Doh, that's what you get when you write code just before leaving work... I'll edit your version in instead :o

Answer (score 0):

x in this case is a list and it is returning a list with the largest length. (xs is a list of lists.)

If you want to test list length you need something like this

```
let allEmpty xs = 
    xs 
    |> List.map (fun x -> x |> List.length) 
    |> List.maxBy id = 0
```